# Работа с NetworkStream и StreamReader

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь работать с POP сервером. Отсылаю ему данные, т.е. авторизацию и прошу его вывести кол-во сообщений командой LIST

```
public void Connected(string host, int port, string user, string pass)
{
    client.Connect(host, port);
    netStream = client.GetStream();
    strReader = new StreamReader(netStream);
        byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[1024];
        ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();

        WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("USER " + user + "\r\n");
        netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
        Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

        WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("PASS " + pass + "\r\n");
        netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
        Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

        WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("LIST \r\n");
        netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);

        Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
}
```

Но чтобы  вывести количество сообщений, приходится перед каждой отправкой данных получать ответ и читать строку. Возможно ли как-нибудь после нужной мне команды вывести результат? В данном случае после

```
WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes("LIST \r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
```

А не перед каждым

```
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не понятно. Суть протокола POP в том, что вы шлёте команды и сразу читаете ответ. А по вашим словам получается, что у вас всё наоборот. Так что вообще не понятно, что вы хотите получить.

**UPD**

Ну так отправьте сразу одним буффером.. что-то в таком духе

```
WriteBuffer = enc.GetBytes(
    "USER " + user + "\r\n" 
    + "PASS " + pass + "\r\n" 
    + "LIST \r\n");
netStream.Write(WriteBuffer, 0, WriteBuffer.Length);

Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
```

Только вообще-то это не очень хорошая идея..

Comment: Я не понимаю. Я же говорю: протокол построен на принципе вопрос - ответ. Если вы не будете читать ответ от сервера, то сервер перестанет вообще выполнять ваши запросы, так как встанет на отправке в сокет. Правда вы можете отправить сразу пачку запросов и потом одним чтением получить пачку ответов.

Comment: Тут всё ровно 3 команды и 3 раза читаем т.е. 3 раза вызываем метод readLine(). Возможно ли как нибудь за один раз прочитать одним методом?

Comment: Так сделайте метод, читающий N строк и тогда будете читать одним методом

Comment: private string Reading(int k)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
          Result += strReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
      return Result;
    }
Типа этого?

Comment: Спасибо , буду сидеть разбираться :)